# Integrating Qt with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, qt, eclipse-cdt

I have stuck with problem of building Qt projects in Eclipse. First of all here is the sequence of steps which I went through when I installed Qt plugin.

I develop in Eclipse for Java Developers, so firstly I downloaded CDT plugin for eclipse, using Install Wizard.

Then I downloaded and install latest Qt SDK with all libraries, including libraries for mobile developement.

The next step was downloading and setting up Qt plugin for Eclipse.

After I have done everything, I began to configure Eclipse for work with CDT and Qt.

1) I pointed in Windows->Preferences->Qt this attributes:

[Name: Qt4.7.3]
[BinPath: C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\bin]
[IncludePath: C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\include]

2) I changed Windows->Preferences->C/C++->New CDT Project Wizard->Makefile Project->Builder Settings->Build Command to `mingw32-make`, because it tried to launch `make` instead and of course projects didn't build.

Everything works fine but everytime when I create new Qt or C/C++ Project I have to modify it's ***Builder settings*** properties and ***MakeTarget*** properties, renaming build commands to `mingw32-make`. Moreover when I save project, Eclipse should rebuild it, but I get nothing and have to build it manually, using MakeTarget->Build in debug mode.

Tell me please what did I miss during configuration.